# Windows Form: the Textbox has to show values of variables

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

A Windows Form with a button, a textbox and some radio buttons. a,b,c are variables (integers) which go through some math based on which radio buttons are checked. Let's say that in the end a= 15, b=20, c=10 The idea is that upon clicking the button something like: 
    The Result is: a = 15, b = 20, c = 10 
has to appear as a text in the textbox, where 15, 20 and 10 are the end values of a,b and c. Questions:

- where do I declare the variables?
- where do I perform the math? It's simple stuff:

  ```
  if(radiobutton1.Checked == true)
      a=a+5;
  ```
- how do I get the results in the textbox by clicking the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your variables as private as the first thing in your form. Do your calculation on a button click event:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int a, b, c;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radioButton1.Checked) a = 5; else a = 0;
            if (radioButton2.Checked) b = 5; else b = 0;
            if (radioButton3.Checked) c = 5; else c = 0;
        }
    }
```

You can use `String.Format` to format the output:

```
textBox1.Text = String.Format("a is {0}, b is {1}, c is {2}", a, b, c);
```

of if using VS2015 String interpolation:

```
textBox1.Text = $"a is {a}, b is {b}, c is {c}";
```